# Minecraft grab data from the F3 menu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm relatively new to minecraft modding, and I want to automatically pull some values from the game that get displayed in the F3 menu, like the entity amount. Is there a way how I can easily get those values or the file location where they are saved?

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you using, and what API? (forge/fabric)

Comment: 1.16(.4) fabric, but i also could switch to forge

Comment: I could'nt find anything in fabric or forge's docs about pulling from the f3 menu, but you can count packets to get the entity count.  It may just require some digging.  [Forge docs](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.16.x/) [Fabric wiki](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/)

Comment: thanks, this already helped me a lot